# Testing events that fire multiple times

Tags: node.js, events, testing

So, Im using vows js for testing node apps.

I have some code which emits the same event multiple times.

Vows (0.7.0) seems fine when testing events that fire once, but if your code emits the same event multiple times, vows complains.

A pull request which I believe might solve this problem was submitted over a year ago but nothing seems to have happened with it...

Does anybody know of a test framework which will allow me to test an object which emits the same event n times?

Here's what I mean (in vows):

```
vows.describe("Vows test").addBatch({
"A test ": {
    topic: function () {
        var topic = new(events.EventEmitter);
        for(var i=0; i<10;i++) {
            topic.emit('woot', 'woot');
        }
        return topic;
    },
    on: {
        "woot": {
            "will catch event the woot event" : function (ret) {
                assert.strictEqual(ret, 'woot');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

})

Cheers...

Comment: you could keep track of times an event fired, by incrementing a `value++`